# AppBar remain constant for entire Page Control in Metro Apps?

Tags: html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

Am trying to display AppBar for entire html page in my Metro app.Whenever I click on the other items of the page, immediately  AppBar is disappearing.Can anyone give me advice to set my AppBar remain constant for entire page in Metro App.Here am using **appbar.winControl.show();**.

Answer (score 6):

For JavaScript: appBar.sticky = true;
For XAML: AppBar.IsSticky = true;

This will keep your AppBar on the screen even if you click elsewhere on the page.  But remember that the design guidance is for a transient AppBar that will light-dismiss (disappear when you touch somewhere else).  Here is the guidance for when it should be sticky, from the [guidelines and checklist for app bars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh781231(v=win.10).aspx):

**Do set the app bar's dismissal mode to sticky when displaying contextual commands.**
If you have contextual commands on an app bar, set the mode to sticky while that context exists and turn off the sticky mode when the context is no longer present (such as when a photo is deselected). In sticky mode, the bar doesn't automatically hide when the user interacts with the app. This is useful for multi-select scenarios or when the context involves interaction such as manipulating cropping handles. The bar stays visible while the user performs the actions. The user can still hide the bar by swiping the top or bottom edge of the screen and they can show it again with an edge swipe.

Finally, here is the JS reference for the [sticky property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700576.aspx).